# oracle apex tab region change event

Tags: oracle-apex-20.2

I have region display selector and there are two subregion as child under `rds` as child regions. i want to capture the event as DA when tab page switched , I have tried below approach but it didnt worked ,

```
$('.apex-rds').data('onRegionChange', function(mode, activeTab) {

  if ( activeTab.href == "#SR_monthly") {

      alert('abc');

  }

});
```

Path to application is [Link](https://paths.maxapex.net/apex/f?p=144:38)

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into your application. When I inspected your RDS region I saw that the href is **monthly** and **not SR_monthly** (Please see below screenshot).

[image: RDS href]

Try changing SR_monthly to monthly in your "if condition"